# Alternative to WIN+L

Tags: windows-7, security, software-rec

So I want to lock my screen to prevent anyone to do anything unless they know a password or a combination of hotkeys. WIN+L is not doing a good job because it prevents a few softwares to continue running and I can't see if a task is finished. I want to be able to *see the screen* for the following reasons:

- **Keep a playlist running.** WIN+L cancels any sound.
- **Run a diagnosis program while I go do something else**. It's happened several times that I was running something important and had to leave my laptop alone. When I did the Windows login the software had freezed or crashed.
- **Chrome**. I adore Chrome and everything about it but it's not very safe since I have all my passwords in auto complete. That's the main reason I use WIN+L all the time.
- **Large download files**. It's easy to leave the computer downloading something overnight but can I trust nobody will mess with my stuff or even close the download software?

What is a good tool or software to protect the keyboard and mouse but still show whatever is running?

Comment: win+L does not stop sound for me.

Comment: Windows Media will turn off sound if you turn off Fast User Switching

Comment: What OS are you using @Renan? The version of Windows is relevant.

Comment: @nhinkle Windows 7 Home 32bits

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at [Kid-Key-Lock](http://www.100dof.com/kidkeylock.html). It locks your keyboard/mouse and unlocks them with a password.

Answer (score 0):

You can bind a hotkey to a screensaver.  Go under Personalization/Screensaver.  Select one like Blank Screen and select "On Resume, show Login screen."

Next, you want to bind a shortcut to the screensaver.

http://www.binaryturf.com/windows-7-start-screensavers-ondemand/

Right-click desktop and select New > Shortcut.

> Paste the following location in Type the location of item field in the resulting dialog.
>   %systemroot%\system32\Bubbles.scr /s
>   Note: You can replace “Bubbles.scr” with the screensaver of your choice.
>   Double-click the desktop icon Bubbles.scr to activate the screensaver.

You can also right click it and assign it a hotkey.

Now, you get a screen saver AND a login screen.

Comment: The Bubbles screensaver takes a picture of the current screen and keeps the sound running. I'm looking for one that doesn't hide the screen activity but only prevents anyone else from inputting data.

Comment: You don't have to use the Bubble Screen saver.  That's just a place holder.  Search under your System32 folder (SysWOW64 if you are running x64) and there are all your installed screensavers.

Comment: But does any of them allow me to see what's going on instead of a static picture?

Comment: Oh, I didn't see that part. AFAIK, that is technically impossible.  The login screen runs in a separate secure account.  And that is the only account that can capture CTRL ALT DEL. Short of finding a free Winlogon replacement(none that I am aware of) no program will be able to do this.